# Amazon S3 Multipart upload files larger than 100mb

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files larger than 100mb to Amazon S3 and for that I need multipart upload. I tried with the documents given but I discovered that was an old version of Amazon SDK. So i found the new documentation ([link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-multipart-upload.html)) that worked. Almost. It works as normal for files under 100mb, but when I try to upload a file of about 300mb it returns bad request. The code below works but with smaller files, any ideas?

```
require 'AWS/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\MultipartUploader;
use Aws\Exception\MultipartUploadException;

$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
  'region' => 'us-west-2',
  'version' => 'latest',
  'credentials' => array(
    'key' => 'my-key',
    'secret' => 'my-secret-key',
  ),
));

$uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3Client, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], [
    'bucket' => 'my-bucket',
    'key'    => $_FILES['file']['name'],
]);

try {
    $result = $uploader->upload();
    echo "Upload complete: {$result['ObjectURL']}\n";
} catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Tried again with a basic form and the same upload.php. I am getting errors that `'file'` is an `'unidentified index in upload.php'`. The name of the input is `'file'` and it works with smaller ones again. Anyone can help?

Comment: It looks to me that multipart upload is by  default supported by the `upload` method of the `ObjectUploader` class in v3 of the PHP SDK. [see here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.S3.ObjectUploader.html)

Comment: @asdf Thanks, this works. The problem now is with the server I have the limit of 128MB upload and it won't change. Trying different methods.